# Android SQLITE DB update table not working

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
contactid = 123;
SYNC_SUCCESS = 1;
db.updateSyncStatus(contactid, SYNC_SUCCESS);
```

I have tried the 3 possible ways to update the table in SQLite DB. But its not working. INSERT and DELETE process are working good. Only I am facing problem in the UPDATE. Did I missed anything?

```
    public void updateSyncStatus(String contactid, int syncSuccess) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues CV = new ContentValues();
    CV.put(CONTACTS_SYNC_STATUS, syncSuccess);

    try {
//            db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, CV, CONTACTS_CONTACTID + "='" + contactid + "'", null);    // Tried, Not working
//            db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, CV, CONTACTS_CONTACTID +" = ?", new String[] {contactid});    // Tried, Not Working
        db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, CV, CONTACTS_CONTACTID + " = ?", new String[]{contactid});
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        Log.e(TAG, "UpdateError: " + error);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

**Table Structure:**

```
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + CONTACTS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
            + CONTACTS_NUMBER + " VARCHAR,"
            + CONTACTS_CONTACTID + " VARCHAR,"
            + CONTACTS_SYNC_STATUS + " TINYINT DEFAULT 0" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

Comment: Odds on that it's not working because `contactid` does not match the value in the `CONTACTS_CONTACTID` column. It could be that you should be using `CONTACTS_ID + " = ?"`. However, it all depends upon what the value of `contactid` is and it's impossible to tell what that might be given the code above. I'd suggest editing your question to include the code that sets the value of `contactid`.

Comment: @Gvtha Try to use a System.out.println("CON ID "+contactid); then you will see the value in the LogCat

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is not with the update query. The problem is , before executing the `updateSyncStatus` method, next statement ran and I am getting the output before updating the rows. So I have used the `Handler` to wait for 10 seconds before showing the output.